# How to render Backbone el correctly into the view page

Tags: backbone.js, render, el

I'm trying to working correctly with my first `Backbone` app and trying to render it into my page.

I've wrote this app but I didn't got how I shoud put the app html rendered in the html view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var SearchApp = new Search.Views.App({
        id:"product-name-results"
    });
    SearchApp.render();
});
<script>
```

This is my app

```
var Search = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
}

Search.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Search.Views.App initialize')
    },  
    render:function (options) {
        this.$el.html('hello world');
    }
});
```

Obviously this render method not appending in the `html view`, but how to append it into the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEkV2/1/)

Basically, I changed `id: ''` to `el: ''`, and added HTML container

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've intentionally not added the html element to the page because I would like to create it dynamically only if I need it, is it possible?

Comment: You can conditionally call `render` and left a hidden div. Or, you can Add element you want in render function: `$('body').append(yourView.el)`, note you could use `$el` in this sentence too.